# Copy multiple .txt contents into single file based on character length

Tags: files, scripting

I'm looking to find the largest file within a directory by character count, copy its contents, delete the file and then paste this to another file elsewhere with the end goal being that every file (txt) in the directory is copied into one single complete file in this new order.

I have managed this by sorting the byte size of the file but not by character count.

My only headway ahs been attempting to loop this within the directory containing the files but this just results in an error, I get the impression this code is barking up the wrong tree...

```
du -b *.txt | sort -n | tail -n1
```

Comment: So, one file will contain all of the other files, in thee order of longest to shortest? Is there any marker/delimiter (i.e. `---`) separating each the copies in the one large file? Can, or will, the files contain 2 (or more) byte characters? Try `wc -c *.txt` instead of `du`. Please [edit] your question with any updates/clarification or additional information (don't add it in the comments)

Comment: Does character mean a Unicode character? As in Я equals one character? Consider: echo Я | awk -v FS="" '{sum +=NF} END {print sum}' => 1  / wc -c => 3  / wc -m => 2

Answer (score 2):

With [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), you can use the `o` or `O` [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to sort files easily based on their filesystem metadata, such as the size (which is the byte count).

```
cat -- *.txt(OL) >new-file.tmp &&
rm *.txt &&
mv new-file.tmp new-file.txt
```

These glob qualifiers also let you sort by arbitrary criteria, using `oe` or `OE` and a code snippet that calculates the sort key, or `o+` or `O+` and a shell function that calculates the sort key. So you can use `wc -m` to obtain each file's character count, and use that as a sort key. Since the sort keys are numeric, also pass the `n` glob qualifier, so that `10` is sorted after `9` and not between `1` and `2`.

```
cat -- *.txt(noe\''REPLY=$(wc -m <$REPLY)'\') …
```